# Не получается подключиться к docker-контейнеру через браузер

Tags: windows, docker, containers

На windows имеется docker-контейнер с установленным проектом на django. Запускаю контейнер командой:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:80 [container_name]
```

В логах докера:

```
Performing system checks...


System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 04, 2021 - 11:31:31
Django version 3.2.7, using settings 'search.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Но при попытке открыть в браузере `127.0.0.1:5000`, страница не открывается. Что я делаю не так?

**UPD:**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip install django
RUN pip install djangorestframework
RUN pip install requests

WORKDIR /usr/src/igloo-search
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD python3 manage.py runserver 80
```

Comment: а какой командой вы запускаете `django` внутри контейнера?

Comment: python3 manage.py runserver 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать:

```bsh
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало