# Docker не отрывается сайт

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
   web:
       build: .
       command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
       ports:
           - 8000:8000
```

Написал и запустил простой докер , однако когда перехожу на урлу 127.0.0.1:8000 получаю ошибку, что страница недоступна.

Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы запускать docker , что бы сайт был доступен ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается подключиться к docker-контейнеру через браузер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325254/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-docker-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: вопрос похож, но у меня всё равно проблема.