# Не запускается сайт на django из docker контейнера

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

Изучаю docker и хотел сделать docker контейнер, вот проект github из которого я это хотел сделать:
https://github.com/BrianRuizy/covid19-dashboard

Вот файл docker который я написал:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ADD requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Кто хорошо знает docker можете подсказать в чем проблема, буду очень признателен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325254/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-docker-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80/1325292#1325292

Comment: Что именно не работает? Что вы ожидаете и что работает не так как вы ожидаете и как вы это проверяете?

Comment: @Roman Konoval
This project does not respond when starting and entering the page, that is, a 404 error occurs